# OPC UA-Certificate Based Login

Tags: opc-ua

How can I configure OPC UA Server to use Username & Password?

How can I configure OPC UA Server to use Certificate? I need some sample code to Login with certificate In C#

Anonymous Login for OPC UA Server is working and able to create a session but can  have alternative Login using certification authorization In C#

Comment: This depends on your server.  What server are you using?